# Overlaying a tabular on a lstlisting in a book

Tags: tables, listings, vertical-alignment

I am relatively new to LaTeX and am trying to move a tabular up by about 2cm to overlay a `lstlisting`. The `\hspace` command works as expected; the `\vspace` command however moves the text following  the tabular (without moving the tabular) so the text overlays both the lstlisting and the table. Any suggestions would be very welcome. I want to place the tabular inside the lstlisting box and leave the text where it is.

```
\hspace{11cm}
\vspace{2cm}
\scalebox{0.75}{
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.05cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|}
\hline
 d&c&b&a&9&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1&0\\
\hline
0&0&0&1&1&1&d&f&f&f&f&f&f&f\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\\
\\
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You are also missing `%`  here `\hspace{11cm}%` and here`\scalebox{0.75}{%`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and all your help. This now works fine

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the vspace before the hspace and leave a blank line before the vspace, so it is working in vertical mode.

Comment: Thanks David - still a lot to learn. this is a great forum  - now works fine